# find array value that index matches another array values

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following 2 arrays

```
tokenIds = [0,1,3]
```

and

```
strings = ["hello", "foo", "goodbye", "bar"]
```

**what would be the best way to create a new array with the elements in "strings" array which index's match the values of "tokenIds" array?**

Such as creating a new array like the following

```
newstrings = ["hello", "foo", "bar"]
```

I have tried the following:

```
const newstrings = strings.filter(index => tokenIds.includes(tokenIds.index));
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just `map` the `tokenIds` array:

```js
const newstrings = tokenIds.map(i => strings[i]);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const tokenIds = [0,1,3]
const strings = ["hello", "foo", "goodbye", "bar"]

const result = strings.filter((str,idx) => tokenIds.includes(idx))
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

May not be the best way to do it, but produces the result you require.

```js
tokenIds = [0,1,3]
strings = ["hello", "foo", "goodbye", "bar"]
newstrings = []
for(var id in tokenIds)
{
  newstrings.push(strings[tokenIds[id]]);
}
console.log(newstrings);
```